# How to Authenticate logged in user in NestJs with Swagger

Tags: node.js, authentication, swagger, nestjs

I just started using nestjs for a project. I have successfully logged in users and token returned. Now using the token to authorize users is the problem. Trying to get **all users** has been returning **"unauthorized access"**

I am also thinking I didn't put the token correctly or so. In the swagger authorization UI, I supplied 
`Bearer someTokenGoesHere` into the input box

Image below
[image]

This is my code
main.ts
Swagger configuration in main.ts

```
  const options = new DocumentBuilder().addBearerAuth()
    .setTitle('My app')
    .setDescription('My app API description')
    .setVersion('1.0')
    .addTag('Tags')
    .build();
  const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, options);
  SwaggerModule.setup('', app, document);
```

User controller

```
import { Controller, Post, Body, Get, Param, UseGuards } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { CreateUserDto } from './create-user.dto';
import { LoginUserDto } from './login-user.dto';
import { AuthService } from 'src/auth/auth.service';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { AdminGuard } from 'src/guards/admin.guard';
import { ApiBearerAuth, ApiBasicAuth } from '@nestjs/swagger';

@Controller('user')
export class UserController {
    constructor(private userService: UserService,
        private authService: AuthService) { }

    @Post('login')
    async login(@Body() loginDTO: LoginUserDto) {
        const user = await this.userService.login(loginDTO);

        const newob = {
            id: user._id
        }

        const payload = {
            userId: user._id,
            email: user.Email,
        }

        const token = await this.authService.signPayLoad(payload);
        return { newob, token };
    }

    @Post('register')
    async register(@Body() createDTO: CreateUserDto) {
        const user = await this.userService.register(createDTO);
        const newob = {
            id: user._id
        }
        const payload = {
            firstname: user.FirstName,
            lastname: user.LastName
        };
        const token = await this.authService.signPayLoad(payload);
        return newob;
    }

    @Get('all')
    @ApiBearerAuth()
    @UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
    async getAllUsers() {
        return await this.userService.getAllUsers();

    }

    @Post('confirm/:token')
    async confirmEmail(@Param() token: string) {
        const user = await this.userService.ConfirmEmail(token);
        return user;
    }

}
```

Can someone please help me out
Thanks

Comment: The best way to figure this out would be to use your browser's dev tools to see the request when using your application i.e. how are tokens sent for every request made after logging in. Swagger is a just a UI for sending requests to your routes, you can send whatever data using the Swagger UI. In NestJS, you can also create examples for your specs I believe using annotations for swagger.

Comment: Try just the token without the `Bearer` word

Answer (score 1):

**these settings worked for me:**

**main.ts**

```
const config = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle('Nestjs Auth')
    .setDescription('Portfolio 1')
    .setVersion('1.0')
    .addBearerAuth(
      {
        type: 'http',
        scheme: 'bearer',
        bearerFormat: 'JWT',
      },
      'access-token',
    )
    .build();

const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, config);
  SwaggerModule.setup('api', app, document, {
    swaggerOptions: {
        persistAuthorization: true, // this
    }});
```

**user.controller.ts**

```
import { Controller, Get, Post, Body, SetMetadata, UseGuards, Req } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UserService } from './users.service';
import { AuthGuard } from 'src/auth/auth.guard';
import { ApiBearerAuth, ApiBody, ApiHeader } from '@nestjs/swagger';


export const IS_PUBLIC_KEY = 'isPublic';
export const Public = () => SetMetadata(IS_PUBLIC_KEY, true);

@Controller('users')
export class UsersController {
  constructor(private readonly usersService: UserService) {}
  
  @Get('/getUsers')
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard)
  @ApiBearerAuth('access-token')
  async getUsers(){
    return this.usersService.getusers();
  }
}
```

the key in `@ApiBearerAuth('access-token')` should match with the key provided in `main.ts`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it, I appreciate your suggestions. I was extracting email that wasn't present in the payload. so I decided to log it and discovered it was null. Then I logout payload, I discovered I was passing User Id into the payload. So I change to id.

The result is

```
async findByPayLoad(payload: any) {
        const { userId } = payload;
        return await this.userModel.findById(userId)

    }
```